# how to use TumbleWeed secure transport via command line only

Tags: windows, file-transfer, tumbleweed

We have been told that we have to use a piece of software called TumbleWeed Secure Transport to transport files between our selves and the other company.  I can get it to work with the GUI but not with the command line.

Part of the issues I am having is the GUI will open even when using the command line:

```
C:\Progra~1\Tumbleweed\STClient\STclient.exe httpsu://user:pass@hostname.com:443/inbox/ C:\temp\File /prefNoAskSched /prefASC
```

The GUI will not disappear at all and the batfile does not return till the GUI is manually closed.

We do not want to use the GUI as the users have a bad habit of braking things if we let them touch it so automation seems far safer.

Has anyone had any experience with this app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it to work with the following command line:

```
C:\Progra~1\Tumbleweed\STClient\STclient.exe httpsu://user:password6@hostaddress.com:443 /inbox/ C:\temp\ACEJON /Remote-Site SITENAME /prefNoAskSched /prefASC /hidden /log /quitWhenDone
```